# What is irrational number with the least/lowest irrationality?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The golden ratio has been called as "the most irrational number", based on a particular method called a continued fraction method. Using this continued fraction method the golden ratio has been stated as "the most irrational number". My question is: If there's a number with the greatest irrationality, then what is irrational number with the lowest irrationality among all irrational numbers ?

Comment: The problem is how to measure the irrationality of a number. There are many possibles criterions, For example, since my area of math's is Probabilistic, i could choose normality for a measure of irrationality. In this case, golden ratio wouldn't be "the most irrational number"

Comment: What is "the most irrational number" according to you ? : D

Comment: Newly, if I choose normality like criteria, there are only a few known of numbers that we know are normal numbers. For example 0.12345678... or 0.23571113... (the first one is "concatenate all natural numbers" and the second is "concatenate all prime numbers"). Now, with a probabilistic approach, both of them have the same irrationality. Objectively speaking, I don't have a "most irrational number"

Comment: Moreover, intuitively a good notion of measure of irrationality will be defined trough the decimal expansion of the number, but for how many irrationals do you know the decimal expansion?

Comment: Not much I guess...

Comment: @sebastianngok Can you please provide references? Where has $\varphi$ been called the "most irrational number"? What is the precise mathematical meaning of this expression?

Comment: @PaoloFranchi, I saw it at wiki

Comment: $\phi$ has the continued fraction with the smallest partial quotients – they're all ones. So the least irrational irrational would be the one with the biggest partial quotients. But there isn't any such thing, any more than there's a biggest integer or a biggest real number. [You may find it amusing to do a websearch for "least irrational irrational".]

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, the concept **measure of irrationality** of a real number $\alpha$  is, technically speaking, the following specialized notion: it is the infimum of  all real $\mu$ for which there is a positive constant $A$ such that for all rational $\frac pq\ne \alpha$ with $q>0$ one has 
$$|\alpha - \frac pq|>\frac {A}{q^{\mu}}$$ This inequality  indicates how “far” of the real $\alpha$ is a rational  “close” to $\alpha$; in other words, all rational “near” to $\alpha$ determines its “distance” from $\alpha$; Or even, how rational can not approach $\alpha$.

See as example the “*striking inequality*” (Baker) discovered by Mahler in 1953 and today improved,
$$|\pi-\frac pq|>\frac{1}{q^{42}}$$ valid for every rational $\frac pq;\space q> 1$

There is a whole Epica about this topic of measure of irrationality, beginning with Dirichlet and his approximation theorem (1842), Liouville and his discovery of the first known transcendental number (1844), passing through Thue (1909), Siegel (1929), Dyson (1947) and the gold brooch finisher with Klaus Friedrich Roth (1955) and his deep result  which earned him the Fields Medal.

**Theorem** (Roth).- For all algebraic irrational $\alpha$ and all $\epsilon > 0$ the inequation
$$ |\alpha- \frac pq |< \frac{1}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$ has only a finite number of solutions in irreducible rational $\frac pq$ i.e. for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a positive constant $C(\alpha,\epsilon)$ such that for all rational $\frac pq$; $q>0$ one has 
$$|\alpha- \frac pq|>\frac {C(\alpha, \epsilon)}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$
“*The achievement is one that speacks for itself: it closes a chapter, and a new chapter is now opened. Roth’s theorem settles a question which is both of a fundamental nature and of extreme difficulty. It will stand as a landmark in mathematics for as long as mathematics is cultivated*” (Harold Davenport, in his presentation of Roth to the Fields Medal at the International Congress in Edinburgh,1958).

With Liouville, measure of irrationality of a real algebraic $\alpha$ was equal to its degree $n$ and $n$ was successively decreasing (with the discoveries of the above mentioned authors)  till the optimal value $ 2 $ established by Roth.